# crontab - /bin/sh: wget: command not found

Tags: macos, osx-lion, wget, cron

I want to set up a crontab on my Macbook Pro running Lion. I run the usual `crontab -e` and provide a quick job to see if everything is working ok ---

```
*/10 * * * * wget -O - -q -t 1 http://site.local/cron.php
```

10 minutes later I see I've got some "mail" from the system stating ---

```
/bin/sh: wget: command not found
```

I do have wget installed as I can run the program from the command line

How do I fix this error? Does my crontab or `.bash_profile` require a shebang?

Comment: Where is your `wget`? Just supply the full path in your crontab.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's probably something to do with your environment being different when it's run as a cron job (ie the `PATH` environment variable is different than what you're using from a bash terminal).

In your bash terminal, use `which` to figure out which `wget` is being used:

```
laptop [ ~ ]: which wget
/opt/local/bin/wget
```

Then use the full path in the cron job:

```
*/10 * * * * /opt/local/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 http://site.local/cron.php
```

For cron jobs, I usually have it run a bash script instead of specifying the command directly in the crontab. It's a bit easier to debug and keeps the crontab a bit cleaner.

Comment: `/usr/bin/which: illegal option -- -` is what I get when I run `which`

Comment: @allanb Is that what you get when you run `which wget`? Are you sure?

Comment: `MacBook-Pro:~ allan$ which wget`
`/usr/bin/which: illegal option -- -`
`usage: which [-as] program ...`

Comment: That's really weird. You could try using mac's spotlight search with this:    mdfind -name wget | grep -E "/wget$"     might get more answers than one though

Comment: In any case, using the whole path worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

To find out where a certain command is located try:

```
which wget
```

or

```
which <certain-command>
```

The output should provide the path of the executable. For example:

```
linux-dgr7:~ # sudo which wget
/usr/bin/wget
```

then change the entry like so:

```
*/10 * * * * /usr/bin/wget -O - -q -t 1 http://site.local/cron.php
```

If the wget does not come up after doing which... you should add the location to the PATH variable.

```
PATH=$PATH:/where/ever/path/is
```

or

```
PATH=$PATH:/opt/wget
```

Comment: You shouldn't need `sudo` for `which`.