# cronjob not finding commands

Tags: bash, script, shell-script, cronjob

I am running (and also new to) OS X El Capitan. I have a user cronjob that is using some basic commands that I got via brew. `wget` and `s3cmd`

I have the cronjob executing a shel script in my user bin, but the cronjob is not finding the commands and throwing mail messages at me that say...

```
script.sh: line 4: wget: command not found
```

but when I run the script myself it goes fine. I get this probably has something to do with the user that cronjob are running under and the PATH, but IDK how to go about changing it. Any ideas?

Comment: Check out this [SuperUser](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://superuser.com/questions/458352/crontab-bin-sh-wget-command-not-found&ved=0ahUKEwiB5d654K3LAhUMvIMKHW5sAVIQFggiMAI&usg=AFQjCNH9Ksz7QpvKlREF3-j317LSR4JPJw&sig2=6tC3JdpRI3ZfsncTuukZrg) post and it will probably fix your issue.

Comment: thanks I found that before but I must have had a type when I tried it because it didn't work....working now